# Where do files deleted via apache.commons.io.FileUtils deleteDirectory go?

Tags: java, delete-file, apache-commons

I suppose its not *that* important, however I have no idea how the files get deleted. They simply cease to exist. They're not in the recycle bin.

I looked in Apache Common IO's documentation and couldn't find anything about how the file/directory is deleted other than *that* the file is deleted. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FileUtils.delete()` and `FileUtils.deleteDirectory()` methods call into the `java.io.FileSystem` class, which is backed by native code. This essentially means that the `delete()` method delegates the actual deletion to the underlying OS and, consequently, to the file system on your drive.

Recycle bin is usually a GUI feature, it has nothing to do with the file system. On the file system level, there's no such thing as a "recycle bin" - the files are usually deleted with very limited ability to recover them. You can of course use some utilities to try and recover such file, however, this heavily depends on the file system you use.